# Canvas Rotation plus onTouchEvent method

Tags: android, rotation, android-canvas, touch-event

I have created a bar graph using an inflated canvas. The problem is that it is upside down. I can flip it using the following code in the onDraw method, but it messes up the onTouchEvent method:

```
public void onDraw(final Canvas canvas) {
    int width = super.getWidth();
    int height = super.getHeight();
    canvas.scale(1f, -1f, width * 0.5f, height * 0.5f);

    //more code after that...
}
```

[image: Upside down bar graph]

The problem in the onTouchEvent is that it is recognizing where the bars where before the canvas was flipped. You can see what happens when I click where the original location was in the photo below (it initiates the pop when it shouldn't):

[image: Flipped canvas]

This is what my onTouchEvent method looks like:

```
public boolean onTouchEvent( MotionEvent event) {
 super.onTouchEvent(event);

 int x = (int)event.getX();
 int y = (int)event.getY();
 xStored = x; yStored=y;
 if (event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP){

 }else if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN){
        System.out.println("Touching down!");
        if(x<50&&y<50){
                Tabs.popupDatePicker();
        }else{
                if(!drawNew){
                for(Rect rect : rectangles){
                 if(rect.contains(x,y)){
                     System.out.println("Touched Rectangle, start activity."+x+","+y);
                     drawNew = true; 

                     invalidate();
                 }else{

                 }
                 }
             }else{
                   drawNew = false; 
                   invalidate();
             }
    }

         }else if(event.getAction()==MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){

         }
              this.postInvalidate();
             return true;
}
```

This is the Draw class that I am using to initiate the Rectangles for the bar graph.

```
public class Draw extends View implements Runnable {
        Paint paint = new Paint();
        List<Rect> rectangles;
        Canvas mCanvas;
        boolean drawNew = false;
        int xStored,yStored;
        int currentRectangle = 0;

        public Draw(Context context) {
            super(context);
            new Thread(this).start();         
        }

        @Override
        protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
            // Compute the height required to render the view
            // Assume Width will always be MATCH_PARENT.
            int width = hh;
            canvasHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
            setMeasuredDimension(width, canvasHeight);
        }

        int x = 0;
        @SuppressLint("DrawAllocation")
        @Override
        public void onDraw(final Canvas canvas) {
            int width = super.getWidth();
            int height = super.getHeight();
                //canvas.scale(1f, -1f,
                  //      width * 0.5f, height * 0.5f);
                mCanvas = canvas;
                super.onDraw(canvas);
                int colWidth = super.getWidth()/24;

                rectangles =  new ArrayList<Rect>();

                Double[] energyData = {1.2,2.4,2.0,1.75,2.3,3.1,2.2,0.2,0.6,1.2,1.6,2.2,1.2,2.4,2.0,1.75,2.3,3.1,2.2,0.2,0.6,1.2,1.6,2.2};
                int maxPosition = 0;
                for(int i=0;i<energyData.length;i++){
                    if(i!=0){
                        if(energyData[i]>energyData[i-1]){
                            maxPosition = i;
                        }
                    }
                }

                for(int i=0;i<energyData.length;i++){
                    if(i%3==0){
                        paint.setColor(Color.rgb(104,159,120));
                    }else if(i%3==1){
                        paint.setColor(Color.rgb(141,186,147));
                    }else{
                        paint.setColor(Color.rgb(38,143,76));
                    }
                    int a = 2+(i*colWidth);
                    int b = (i*colWidth)+colWidth;
                    double heightIndicator = 0.80;
                    if(MainActivity.isLarge){
                        heightIndicator = 0.8;
                    }
                    int c = (int) (height*(energyData[i]/energyData[maxPosition])*heightIndicator);
                    final Rect currentRect = new Rect(a, 0, b, c);
                    rectangles.add(currentRect);
                    if(!reselect){
                        if(x==0){
                            Tabs.playSound();
                            x++;
                        }
                        if(currentRectangle>=i){
                            canvas.drawRect(currentRect, paint);
                        }
                    }else{
                        canvas.drawRect(currentRect, paint);
                    }
                }

                if(drawNew){
                    paint.setColor(Color.DKGRAY);
                    Path path = new Path();

                      path.moveTo(xStored,15);

                      path.lineTo(xStored+15,30);

                      path.lineTo(xStored+15,15);

                      canvas.drawPath(path, paint);
                      int left = xStored+15;
                      int top = canvasHeight*3/4;
                      int right = (int) (xStored+(canvasWidth/2.5));
                      int bottom = 15;
                      Rect newRect = new Rect(left, top, right, bottom);
                      canvas.drawRect(newRect, paint);
                      canvas.save();  // save the current state of the canvas
                      canvas.scale(1f, -1f,
                            width * 0.5f, height * 0.5f);
                      double centerX = 0.5 *(left+right);
                      double centerY = 0.5 *(bottom+top);
                      int textSize = 30;
                      if(MainActivity.isLarge){
                          textSize = 40;
                      }

                      int rectWidth = newRect.width();
                      int rectHeight = newRect.height();
                      int paddingIntervalTop = -(rectHeight/40);
                      int paddingIntervalRight = (rectWidth/2)+(rectWidth/4);
                      int moveCenterX = right-paddingIntervalRight; 
                      int moveCenterY = ((int) centerY)+paddingIntervalTop;
                      //decrease this to increase spacing between text
                      int cutInterval = 4;
                      paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
                      paint.setTextSize(textSize); 
                      paint.setTypeface(Tabs.font);
                      canvas.drawText("3AM", moveCenterX, moveCenterY, paint);
                      canvas.drawText("$0.13", moveCenterX, moveCenterY-(rectHeight/cutInterval), paint);
                      paint.setColor(Color.BLUE);
                      paint.setTextSize((float) (textSize*0.7));
                      canvas.drawText("16kWh", moveCenterX, moveCenterY-((rectHeight/cutInterval+2)*2), paint);
                      canvas.drawText("74F", moveCenterX, moveCenterY-((rectHeight/cutInterval+4)*3), paint);

                }else{

                }

            }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `Matrix` to rotate your `Rect` objects:

```
Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
matrix.setRotate(180, (rect.right - rect.left) / 2, (tallestRect.top - tallestRect.bottom) / 2);
matrix.mapRect(rect);
```

your pivot point will be the center of your Rect on the X axis and the center of the image or the tallest Rect on the Y axis.

Comment: Is the Matrix class android.graphics or android.opengl?

Comment: android.graphics.Matrix

Comment: Where you are initialising your rectangles var?

Comment: I am initializing the rectangles in the onDraw method (see edits above for complete code).

Comment: You are recreating objects with the same parameters in your onDraw() method. It's not a good practice and can lead to performance problems. You should think about refactoring your code. But for instance, you should try to rotate your rect just after this line: final Rect currentRect = new Rect(a, 0, b, c); -> Matrix matrix = new Matrix(); matrix.setRotate(180, (currentRect.right - currentRect.left) / 2, height / 2); matrix.mapRect(rect);